# Best way to group two dataframes in pandas and perform operation on matching groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Given two dataframes, I want to **group them by some columns and for each pair of groups with the same group key perform some operation**, modifying the first dataframe in the process. There should be left-join on groups, ie. if groups in the second dataframe that are not in the first one should be ignored. Each operation will compute some additional columns for the first dataframe.

Some details on my case - I'm working in TV Ads domain and have to compute some metrics for each data point, but these metrics makes sense only after grouping records into buckets of `channel, visitor_id, date`.

Performance is important - if possible, I would like to avoid making multiple copies in memory, since these datasets are huge - up to 20 mln records.

I think an example will be more clear:

```py
import pandas as pd

first = pd.DataFrame([
    {'visitor_id': 123, 'channel': 'Test1', 'duration': 1},
    {'visitor_id': 123, 'channel': 'Test1', 'duration': 5},
    {'visitor_id': 123, 'channel': 'Test1', 'duration': 7},
    {'visitor_id': 123, 'channel': 'Test2', 'duration': 2},
    {'visitor_id': 234, 'channel': 'Test1', 'duration': 3},
    {'visitor_id': 234, 'channel': 'Test2', 'duration': 4},
    {'visitor_id': 234, 'channel': None, 'duration': 4},
])

second = pd.DataFrame([
    {'visitor_id': 123, 'channel': 'Test1', 'price': 100},
    {'visitor_id': 123, 'channel': 'Test2', 'price': 200},
    {'visitor_id': 567, 'channel': 'Test2', 'price': 100},
    {'visitor_id': 234, 'channel': 'Test1', 'price': 100},
    {'visitor_id': 234, 'channel': 'Test2', 'price': 300},
    {'visitor_id': 234, 'channel': None, 'price': 400},
])
```

```py
# function I want to apply to each group, in reality it's more complex
# and need to access group records directly
def add_cost_per_second(first_group, second_group):
    first_group['cost_per_second'] = second_group['price'].sum() / first_group['duration']
    return first_group
```

I want to apply `add_cost_per_second` to each pair of groups, modifying the first group in the process.

---

I've tried to play with `groupby` and `get_group`, but it's not working with NaN values - they're automatically dropped. Maybe I could manually check for it beforehand?

Anyway, solution I'm using right now looks like this:

```py
def apply_for_groups(df1: pd.DataFrame, df2: pd.DataFrame, callback, *groups_names, **kwargs) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # we can't use groupby, because it's dropping groups with np.nan inside
    # probably can be further optimized, but query is already considered pretty fast
    # https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html
    result = []
    unique = df1.drop_duplicates(groups_names)
    for group_keys in unique[list(groups_names)].itertuples(index=False):
        q = " & ".join(
            f"({name} == '{key}')" if not pd.isna(key) else f"({name}.isna())"
            for name, key in zip(groups_names, group_keys)
        )
        # can we get rid of that .copy()?
        result.append(callback(df1.query(q).copy(), df2.query(q).copy(), **kwargs))
    # is there a better way? Like, send original slice to callback and modify it
    # instead of returning dataframes and concatenating them?
    return pd.concat(result)
```

```py
# usage
result = apply_for_groups(first, second, add_cost_per_second, 'visitor_id', 'channel')
```

Is there a better way to group two dataframes by columns and zip them together?

Comment: The examples don't include a date column, which you said is part of the groups. Also it would be clearer what you are trying to accomplish if you show the desired output given the example data.

Comment: I wanted to simplify an example, so I've used two groups instead of three. I can remove mention of a 'date' column if it's misleading and I'll try to adjust the example to be more clear. Basically, I'm looking for the fastest way to group two dataframes on the same columns and get values from both for equal keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try `df.join`. You'll want the index in the second dataframe to match column names in the first, or to use the same columns for indexes in both dataframes. This should work if the combinations of visitor_id and channel are unique and you replace NaN with a value (here 'No channel').

```
first['channel'] = first['channel'].fillna('No channel') 
second['channel'] = second['channel'].fillna('No channel') 
first.join(second.set_index(['visitor_id', 'channel'], how='left', on=['visitor_id', 'channel'])

   visitor_id     channel  duration  price
0         123       Test1         1    100
1         123       Test1         5    100
2         123       Test1         7    100
3         123       Test2         2    200
4         234       Test1         3    100
5         234       Test2         4    300
6         234  No channel         4    400
```

Comment: what if there is no common index? In my case I have two dataframes of different sorts of records, but where the records all have timestamps. I want to collect both dataframes into common time groups, e.g. say all the records from df1 and df2 per day. Trying to merge the dataframes seems bad since the columns are orthogonal and the records have nothing directly to do with each other. But I want to be able to jointly iterate over both together over common grouped time periods... I also don't really want to define the group index in advance, though I suppose I can...

Comment: If they don't have any relation, you don't need to iterate over them at the same time, use a Grouper for the groupings -- pd.Grouper(key="timestamp_column", freq="1D"), and then do your transformations on the daily groups. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html for more details.

Comment: That's what I'm doing for one dataframe, but I'm not sure how to use Grouper for two dataframes "in sync". And the relation they have is time, but that's it. I want groups of both of them with common time groups that I can then iterate over "in sync". With days maybe it would be ok to do some kind of lookup to match the groups, but actually I am doing it with seconds so it would be much better to just construct the groups in such a way that each group has the relevant stuff in that time period from both dataframes.

Comment: I made a question with details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78084763/collect-common-groups-on-non-index-column-across-two-dataframes