# Collect common groups on non-index column across two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Here are two dataframes grouped how I want them:

```
last5s = pd.Timestamp.now().replace(microsecond=0) - pd.Timedelta('5s')
dates = pd.date_range(last5s, periods = 5, freq='s')

N=10
data1 = np.random.randint(0,10,N)
data2 = np.random.randint(0,10,N)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': np.random.choice(dates, size=N), 'A': data1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': np.random.choice(dates, size=N), 'B': data2})

print(df1)
print(df2)
print()

g1 = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='1s'))
print("g1:")
for time, group in g1:
    print('time:', time)
    print(group)
    print()
    
print()
g2 = df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='1s'))
print('g2:')
for time, group in g2:
    print('time:', time)
    print(group)
    print()
```

Output (e.g.):

```
            timestamp  A
0 2024-03-01 10:05:26  7
1 2024-03-01 10:05:25  8
2 2024-03-01 10:05:28  1
3 2024-03-01 10:05:24  2
4 2024-03-01 10:05:28  5
5 2024-03-01 10:05:27  4
6 2024-03-01 10:05:24  6
7 2024-03-01 10:05:26  3
8 2024-03-01 10:05:26  8
9 2024-03-01 10:05:28  8
            timestamp  B
0 2024-03-01 10:05:25  1
1 2024-03-01 10:05:26  6
2 2024-03-01 10:05:25  5
3 2024-03-01 10:05:28  7
4 2024-03-01 10:05:27  7
5 2024-03-01 10:05:28  1
6 2024-03-01 10:05:28  4
7 2024-03-01 10:05:25  0
8 2024-03-01 10:05:24  6
9 2024-03-01 10:05:24  5

g1:
time: 2024-03-01 10:05:24
            timestamp  A
3 2024-03-01 10:05:24  2
6 2024-03-01 10:05:24  6

time: 2024-03-01 10:05:25
            timestamp  A
1 2024-03-01 10:05:25  8

time: 2024-03-01 10:05:26
            timestamp  A
0 2024-03-01 10:05:26  7
7 2024-03-01 10:05:26  3
8 2024-03-01 10:05:26  8

time: 2024-03-01 10:05:27
            timestamp  A
5 2024-03-01 10:05:27  4

time: 2024-03-01 10:05:28
            timestamp  A
2 2024-03-01 10:05:28  1
4 2024-03-01 10:05:28  5
9 2024-03-01 10:05:28  8


g2:
time: 2024-03-01 10:05:24
            timestamp  B
8 2024-03-01 10:05:24  6
9 2024-03-01 10:05:24  5

time: 2024-03-01 10:05:25
            timestamp  B
0 2024-03-01 10:05:25  1
2 2024-03-01 10:05:25  5
7 2024-03-01 10:05:25  0

time: 2024-03-01 10:05:26
            timestamp  B
1 2024-03-01 10:05:26  6

time: 2024-03-01 10:05:27
            timestamp  B
4 2024-03-01 10:05:27  7

time: 2024-03-01 10:05:28
            timestamp  B
3 2024-03-01 10:05:28  7
5 2024-03-01 10:05:28  1
6 2024-03-01 10:05:28  4
```

How do I "join" the groups together such that I can iterate over them together? E.g. I want to be able to do:

```
for time, group1, group2 in somehow_joined(g1,g2):
    <do stuff with group1 and group2 in this common time group>
```

Comment: Do you want to do "stuff" with `A` and `B` at the same time e.g. compute `A + B`? Or still process `A` and `B` separately, just as a group with the same timestamp?

Comment: I am making an animation, so I want to plot stuff from A and B in a frame of an animation, or dynamic plot. So I don't need them to be in the same dataframe, if that's what you're asking. I guess I don't compute A + B or anything.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Something along the lines of Andrej's answer should work fine then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do:

```
for t, d1 in g1:
    d2 = g2.get_group(t)
    if d2 is None:
        print("I don't want this")
        continue

    print(d1)
    print('-'*10)
    print(d2)
    print('='*30)
```

Output:

```
            timestamp  A
0 2024-02-29 19:10:14  0
3 2024-02-29 19:10:14  7
7 2024-02-29 19:10:14  1
----------
            timestamp  B
1 2024-02-29 19:10:14  0
3 2024-02-29 19:10:14  6
5 2024-02-29 19:10:14  9
6 2024-02-29 19:10:14  4
==============================
            timestamp  A
2 2024-02-29 19:10:15  2
5 2024-02-29 19:10:15  8
6 2024-02-29 19:10:15  2
9 2024-02-29 19:10:15  6
----------
            timestamp  B
8 2024-02-29 19:10:15  9
==============================
            timestamp  A
1 2024-02-29 19:10:16  3
4 2024-02-29 19:10:16  9
8 2024-02-29 19:10:16  6
----------
            timestamp  B
2 2024-02-29 19:10:16  6
4 2024-02-29 19:10:16  6
==============================
```

Comment: This will skip any timestamps that aren't present in `g1` and give a `KeyError` for any which aren't in `g2`

Comment: @Nick Hmm yeah, I like the general idea though. The itertools thing is effective but a little opaque. Maybe combining all the keys from both groups into a list, iterating that, and calling get_group on both g1 and g2 (checking for KeyErrors) might be a good way to go. Didn't know get_group was a thing, seems handy.

Comment: This general approach feels nicest to me, though as Nick says a few extra steps are needed to deal with potential non-overlap of the group keys.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I've understood your question well, but you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

g1 = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="timestamp", freq="1s"))
g2 = df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="timestamp", freq="1s"))

for t, g in groupby(sorted([*g1, *g2], key=lambda k: k[0]), lambda k: k[0]):
    print(t)
    print("-" * 80)
    for _, group in g:
        print(group)
    print()
```

Prints (for example):

```
2024-03-01 00:14:25
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            timestamp  A
7 2024-03-01 00:14:25  0
9 2024-03-01 00:14:25  7
            timestamp  B
1 2024-03-01 00:14:25  0
3 2024-03-01 00:14:25  4
7 2024-03-01 00:14:25  1

2024-03-01 00:14:26
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            timestamp  A
5 2024-03-01 00:14:26  5
            timestamp  B
2 2024-03-01 00:14:26  4
5 2024-03-01 00:14:26  0
6 2024-03-01 00:14:26  9

2024-03-01 00:14:27
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            timestamp  A
0 2024-03-01 00:14:27  4
4 2024-03-01 00:14:27  6
            timestamp  B
4 2024-03-01 00:14:27  4
8 2024-03-01 00:14:27  6

2024-03-01 00:14:28
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            timestamp  A
1 2024-03-01 00:14:28  5
8 2024-03-01 00:14:28  8
            timestamp  B
0 2024-03-01 00:14:28  0

2024-03-01 00:14:29
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            timestamp  A
2 2024-03-01 00:14:29  5
3 2024-03-01 00:14:29  4
6 2024-03-01 00:14:29  1
            timestamp  B
9 2024-03-01 00:14:29  6
```

Comment: Hmm interesting, it does seem to work... I am a little confused about how though. Am I guaranteed to get my 'groups' out in a predictable order? It seems like it unpacks both sets of groups into one list and then groups the groups again based on the timestamp keys, which is ok except I need to be sure that e.g. the groups come out in the order g1, g2 in the end, so I know which is which...

Comment: @BenFarmer The python's `sorted()` is stable, so when you create your list `[*g1, *g2]` and the groups share common timestamp, first will be always group from `g1`